# Remove spaces in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know how I can remove spaces in my code. I usually do reformat code, but this does not remove all the doubl spaces and such. I assume there is a way in the preferences but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that this is for Java code (although the general mechanism is true for most file types), you can modify when/how spaces are used in code.

Go to File->Settings->Code Style->Java

If you then click on the Spaces tab you can specify the code layout you want.  After you've done this if you reformat your code it should format according to your preferences.

You can specify this for other types too (General, CSS, JavaScript and so on)

Comment: I could not find an option to remove double white spaces, e.g. make // <many blanks> My comment to // My Comment

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that this setting only applies to "active" java code - commented out blocks are ignored (although other re-factorings such as renaming can effect commented out blocks)

Comment: the reason it won't work on commented blocks because what is inside comments could be anything, not only java code, so no reformat mechanism should apply to them. Also, it is assumed that the code will be formatted before being commented (so you could uncomment, reformat then comment the block you want)